# Controlled Variables in Logistic Regression in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I just learned what controlled variables mean for a project that I am doing, and I was trying to find if sci-kit learn has a controlled variable option. Specifically, does Python have controlled variable (not independent variables) for the logistic regression?

I googled stuff and found nothing for Python. However, I was thinking more basic and that controlled variables means stratifying the group you are interested (say race) and then going analysis on each group based on your x's and y. If this is correct, then I am suppose to interpret the results from those stratified groups, right?

Sorry, I asked two questions, but I am trying to gain much info on this controlled group idea and applications on Python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you may know that control variables are those variables which the experimenter is not interested in studying, but believes that they do have a significant role in the value which your dependent variable takes. So people generally hold the value of this variable a constant when they run their experiments i.e. collecting data.

To give an example assume that you are trying to model the health condition of a person i.e. classify if he is healthy or not and you are considering age, gender and his/her exercise pattern as inputs to your model and want to study how each and every input affects your target variable. But you very well know that the country in which the subject is residing will also have a say on his health condition (which encodes the climate, heath facility etc.). So in order to make sure that this variable (country) is not affecting your model, you make sure that you collect all your data from just one country.

So answering your first question, no python does not account have controlled variables. It just assumes that all the input variables you are feeding in are of the interest to the experimenter.

Coming to your second question, one way of handling control variables it by first grouping the data with respect to it, so that each group now has a constant value for that control variable, now we run Logistic regression or any model for each group separately and then 'pool' the results from different models. But this approach falls apart if the number of levels in your control variable is really high, in which case we generally consider the control variable as an independent variable and feed it to our model.

For more details please refer to [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/17338) or [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/78830), they really have some nice explanations.